# Adding string to ListView from different activity only replaces first item instead of adding more to list

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm working on a project that allows the user to send a string from one activity to a list view in another activity with a button. However, when I try to send data from one activity to the next, the receiving activity replaces the last item sent instead of adding to the list view. Here's my code:
EnterInfoActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.kevin.myapplication.R.id.Done;
import static com.example.kevin.myapplication.R.id.EnterInfo;

public class EnterInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> yearAdapter;
Button Done;
EditText Name;
EditText PName;
Spinner YearSpinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_info);

    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    PName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PName);
    Done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Done);
    YearSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Year);
    yearAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.year_sequence, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    yearAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    YearSpinner.setAdapter(yearAdapter);



    Done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ViewData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("newName", Name.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("newPName", PName.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("Year", YearSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            editor.commit();
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

and heres ViewActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public static final String DEFAULT = " ";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ViewData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    String Name = sharedPreferences.getString("newName",DEFAULT);
    String PName = sharedPreferences.getString("newPName",DEFAULT);
    String Year = sharedPreferences.getString("Year",DEFAULT);

    String PhotoInfo =(Name + "    " + PName + "   " + Year);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV_View);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add(PhotoInfo);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                arrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

Comment: You didnt pass a list you passed only three I dont and have Combined in your String PhotoInfo

Comment: read about an Android Application Lifecycle: OnCreate - onStart - onResume ... Later on, i'd suggest to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to reliably send data to other activities

Answer (score 0):

In ur arrayList you always have the last one . There is no existing list that you are adding to, hence its only showing you the last one

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList;

 ---

arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add(PhotoInfo);
```

From the last 2 lines u can see, u are creating a new list and adding just that one String to it.Hence u can just see the last one.

Answer (score 0):

you must set your **ArrayList as static** and don't renew it every time! you must just create it for one time and each time just add **new** item to it and call **notifyDatasetChanged()**.

```java
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
//set arraylist as static and eager loading for it.
public static ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public static final String DEFAULT = " ";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ViewData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    String Name = sharedPreferences.getString("newName",DEFAULT);
    String PName = sharedPreferences.getString("newPName",DEFAULT);
    String Year = sharedPreferences.getString("Year",DEFAULT);

    String PhotoInfo =(Name + "    " + PName + "   " + Year);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV_View);
    //remove renew arraylist
    arrayList.add(PhotoInfo);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                arrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    //its ok
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```